# Plotly/Dash -- range filter resets on hoverData

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying capture mouse hover events using Dash. I capture the position of the mouse using `hoverData`.

The problem appears when I filter the time series using the range selector or the range slider. The plot correctly reduces to the selected time, but when I hover it with the mouse it resets to the main view (whole main series).

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='stock-plot'
    ),
], className="container")

@app.callback(
    Output('stock-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('stock-plot', 'hoverData')])
def drawStockPrice(hoverData):
    traces = [go.Scatter(
                    x=df.Date,
                    y=df['AAPL.High'],
                    mode='lines',
                    opacity=0.7,
                    connectgaps=True),
            ]
    return {'data': traces,
            'layout': go.Layout(colorway=["#5E0DAC", '#FF4F00', '#375CB1', '#FF7400', '#FFF400', '#FF0056'],
                                          height=600,
                                          title=f"Closing prices",
                                          xaxis={"title": "Date",
                                                 'rangeselector': {'buttons': list([{'count': 1, 'label': '1M',
                                                                                     'step': 'month',
                                                                                     'stepmode': 'backward'},
                                                                                    {'count': 6, 'label': '6M',
                                                                                     'step': 'month',
                                                                                     'stepmode': 'backward'},
                                                                                    {'step': 'all'}])},
                                                 'rangeslider': {'visible': True}, 'type': 'date'},
                                          yaxis={"title": "Price (USD)"},
    )}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure there should be a better solution but this is what I got (Dash v1.6.0):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

layout = go.Layout( colorway=["#5E0DAC", '#FF4F00', '#375CB1', '#FF7400', '#FFF400', '#FF0056'],
                    height=600,
                    title=f"Closing prices",
                    xaxis={"title": "Date",
                           'rangeselector': {'buttons': list([{'count': 1, 'label': '1M',
                                                               'step': 'month',
                                                               'stepmode': 'backward'},
                                                              {'count': 6, 'label': '6M',
                                                               'step': 'month',
                                                               'stepmode': 'backward'},
                                                              {'step': 'all'}]
                                              ),  
                           },
                           'rangeslider': {'visible': True}, 
                           'type': 'date',            
                    },
                    yaxis={"title": "Price (USD)"},
)

traces = [go.Scatter(   x=df.Date,
                        y=df['AAPL.High'],
                        mode='lines',
                        opacity=0.7,
                        connectgaps=True
)]

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='stock-plot',
        figure={
            'data': traces,
            'layout': layout
        }        
    ),
], className="container")

@app.callback(
    Output('stock-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('stock-plot', 'hoverData'),
     Input('stock-plot', 'relayoutData')],
    [State('stock-plot', 'figure')]
)
def drawStockPrice(hoverData, selected, figure):
    data = figure['data']
    layout = figure['layout']

    if selected is not None and 'xaxis.range' in selected:
        layout['xaxis']['range'] = selected['xaxis.range']

    return {'data': data,
            'layout': layout
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I would like to obtain `hoverData` in the data I filtered, but the filter resets when I hover with the mouse. I have edited the questions with a sample code that runs and can reproduce my problem.

Comment: Tony, What if I want to draw something over that graph, like a small circle over the time series where my mouse is at? That's what I would use `hoverData` for

Comment: I see. I have updated the code. There is a `xaxis.range` in the `relayoutData` property of the `Graph` that you could use to set the layout range in your callback.

Comment: If anyone sees this, a more general solution is provided in https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-dash-range-filter-resets-on-hoverdata/31341